# Looking for a way to populate listview from String array

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a problem populating a `ListView` with an I have created. All of the data goes to one column instead of rows. Could you help me to populate it correctly?

```
Dim finalas() As String = arrf.ToArray(GetType(System.String))
For Each element As String In finalas
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(element)
    ListView1.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and looked at finalas to see what it holds. A simple 1-dimensional array of strings should populate by row.

Comment: You should double check that arrf.ToArray is doing what you expect and not placing them all as one element.

Comment: after trying this code:             For i = 0 To 10
                MsgBox(finalas(i))
            Next
it shows every element as it should, but repeats 3 times (there are 3 different records on database) the same record

Comment: Set up an array. `Dim finalas = {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}` and the code works fine. Check your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself, if some one needs it, here you go:

Sub readTextFile()

```
    ' Create new StreamReader instance with Using block.
    Dim path As String = "D:\data.txt"

    Dim st() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path) 'read the file into array of 
    Dim p_1 As String = ""
    Dim p_2 As String = ""
    Dim arrl As Integer = 11


    For Each itm As String In st 'loop the array of string item by item
        Dim Arr() As String = itm.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 'split the string
        Dim name() As String = itm.Split(New String() {"'"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        ' Arr.Skip(1).ToArray -nenuskaito pirmojo
        ' Arr = Arr.Take(Arr.Length - 1).ToArray - nenuskaito paskutinio

        'galutinis array
        p_1 = Arr(1)
        p_2 = Arr(2)

        Dim finarr As New List(Of String)
        finarr.Add(p_1)
        finarr.Add(p_2)
        finarr.Add(name(1))
        For i As Integer = 4 To arrl
            finarr.Add(Arr(((Arr.Length - 1) - arrl) + i))
        Next

        'MsgBox(finarr(0) & finarr(1) & finarr(2) & finarr(3) & finarr(4) & finarr(5) & finarr(6) & finarr(7) & finarr(8) & finarr(9) & finarr(10))

        Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)
        Dim lvItem = New ListViewItem(finarr(0))
        For i = 1 To 10
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(finarr(i))
        Next i
        items.Add(lvItem)
            ListView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray)
        Next

        Return
End Sub
```